Vendor to handle 3rd party integration to access data on behalf of customers
Context: I'm looking to build a B2B software product to provide insights on top of customer data. The data will likely live in other system already (think PSP like Paypal, or ERP like Netsuite).
What would you recommend to use to provide these connections? I'm specifically looking at these criterias:

Has a lot of integration so I can quickly add more if my customer ask for it. - Has a reasonable onboarding flow.
Doesn't cost an arm and a leg
Can output to self-managed warehouse in S3 (not snowflake for example).

I know fivetran is probably the biggest player here (and has a powered by fivetran product that's pretty promising), but I don't love their integration experience + cost. Wonder if folks knows of better alternative
I've searched around and couldn't find any info. Any help is much appreciated.
